# PHP MySQL Sign up with pre defined username and registration id

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to make a website with a member section. To signup on the member section, you must already be in the database. You're given your username and password, then when you signup you can enter your email, address, and password.

So my problem is that I'm getting an error saying that the username or reg_id were incorrect, when I know that I am entering the correct info.

```
else {
    mysql_close($con);
    header("location: index.php?signup&error-msg=Incorrect Username or Registration ID.");
}
```

Here is my Login Form:

```
<form action="function.php?signup" method="post">
  <table cellspacing="20" class="span12">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" name="reg_id" placeholder="Your Registration ID">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" placeholder="Confirm Signup" value="Confirm Signup">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

On the function.php I have a bunch of different functions etc. but the one for the signup form is:

```
elseif (isset($_GET['signup'])) {

  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $reg_id   = $_POST['reg_id'];

  $qry = mysql_query("
    SELECT *
    FROM users
    WHERE username = '$username'
      AND registration_id = '$reg_id' ", $con);

  if (!$qry) {
    mysql_close($con);
    die("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());
  } else {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($qry);
  }

  if ($_POST['username'] == $row["username"] && $_POST['reg_id'] == $row["registration_id"]) {
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email    = $_POST['email'];
    $address  = $_POST['address'];

    $qry = mysql_query("
      INSERT INTO users
        (password, profile_email, profile_address)
      VALUES ('$password', '$email', '$address')", $con);

    if (!$qry) {
      die("Query Failed: " . mysql_error());
    } else {
      header('location: index.php?success-msg=You have successfully signed up');
    }
  }

  else {
    mysql_close($con);
    header("location: index.php?signup&error-msg=Incorrect Username or Registration ID.");
  }

}
```

I'm not sure what I messed up on, or if I even did that right, as I am still learning. I would like to thank anyone who helps me in advance, all help is much appreciated.

-James

Comment: Your INSERT query should probably be an UPDATE one, if people are already in the database. But otherwise - you've not said what the problem you're having is.

Comment: Ohh sorry, I wasn't paying attention enough, ill add that in. my mistake.

Comment: plain text passwords PLEASE dont

Comment: I haven't learned how to encrypt them yet

Comment: As a start, use something basic like `md5`

Comment: You probably already know that the mysql extension you use is deprecated. I just tell you so if you did not know, you can now decide if you want to move on to an alternative extension. http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use update instead of INSERT.
Following is the corrected PATCH:

```
$qry = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password='$password',profile_email='$email',profile_address='$address' 
        WHERE registration_id='$reg_id'");
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :) - I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Hi @TehJamDude, if my answer is solution to your question, please consider it marking as solution as other users with same problem can benefit from it.Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`$_POST['username']` should be `$_POST['name']` accoding to HTML form.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, it is now being successful, I just need to make it UPDATE rather then INSERT, I'll see if it works after that.

Answer (score 1):

you could use something like this :

```
if (isset($_GET['signup'])){//if

    $username = $_POST['name'];
    $reg_id = $_POST['reg_id'];

    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND registration_id='$reg_id'", $con) or die(mysql_error());
    $row=mysql_num_rows($qry);

    if($row == '1'){ ///if regcode exists
    ////insert into database
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];

    $qry2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO
            users(password,profile_email,profile_address)
            VALUES ('$password','$email','$address')", $con) or die(mysql_error());
    header('location: index.php?success-msg=You have successfully signed up');

    }///if regcode exists
    else{
      ///didn't find the reg id
      header("location: index.php?signup&error-msg=Incorrect Username or Registration ID.");

    }


    }//if
```

Comment: It would work, except the $qry2 would have to be an UPDATE, as I was explained by one of the answers, thanks for putting you work into helping me!

Comment: Yes sure sorry about that 
it should be Update